# VisualVM crashes on mac

Tags: visualvm, macos-high-sierra

I'm facing some trouble working on VisualVM on Mac.

Whenever I run the visualvm app (either from the app installed or by going to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm (unix executable file) it opens the terminal, for a moment visualvm also starts and then the following is printed in the terminal and visualvm closes

Last login: Thu Dec  7 22:15:06 on ttys000
    Kingshuks-MacBook-Pro:~ kingshuk$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm ; exit;
    logout
    Saving session...
    ...copying shared history...
    ...saving history...truncating history files...
    ...completed.

```
[Process completed]

I have recently upgraded from Sierra to High Sierra. I think I have used visualvm before this upgrade, might be once or twice though.

Any help to resolve this issue would be great..!! Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

I tried to use 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true but got the following error. Guess this is because I don't have netbeans installed??


Last login: Sat Dec  9 16:21:57 on console
Kingshuks-MacBook-Pro:~ kingshuk$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/‌Home/bin/jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/‌​Home/bin/jvisualvm: No such file or directory
Kingshuks-MacBook-Pro:~ kingshuk$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Saturday, December 9, 2017 4:41:03 PM EST
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Java VisualVM
  Operating System        = Mac OS X version 10.13.1 running on x86_64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_152; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.152-b16; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_152-b16
  Java Home               = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (visualvm); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /Users/kingshuk
  Current Directory       = /Users/kingshuk
  User Directory          = /Users/kingshuk/Library/Application Support/VisualVM/8u131
  Cache Directory         = /Users/kingshuk/Library/Caches/VisualVM/8u131
  Installation            = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/visualvm
                            /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/profiler
                            /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/MRJToolkit.jar
  Application Classpath   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/boot.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/core/core.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/core_visualvm.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/com-sun-tools-visu

alvm-modules-startup_ja.jar

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash.setRunning(Splash.java:119)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:257)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Kingshuks-MacBook-Pro:~ kingshuk$
```

I was also able to notice that the visualvm script calls the nbexec file. And when I tried to run that independently, I got the below error on the console.

```
Last login: Wed Dec 20 17:56:02 on ttys000
Kingshuks-MacBook-Pro:~ kingshuk$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/nbexec ; exit;
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/cache/lastModified/all-checksum.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.compareAndUpdateFile(Stamps.java:444)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.stamp(Stamps.java:331)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.moduleJARs(Stamps.java:282)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.file(Stamps.java:168)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.asByteBuffer(Stamps.java:173)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.asStream(Stamps.java:129)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.checkPopulateCache(Stamps.java:540)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.file(Stamps.java:160)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.asByteBuffer(Stamps.java:173)
    at org.netbeans.Stamps.asByteBuffer(Stamps.java:153)
    at org.netbeans.Archive.<init>(Archive.java:81)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.initializeCache(JarClassLoader.java:68)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader.run(MainImpl.java:298)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:559)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:154)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:46)
    at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Thanks..!!

Comment: Please open Termainal.app and run the following command from terminal window: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true`. Post the output, so I can see what is going on.

Comment: Hey Sorry, am kind of new to stackoverflow. Couldn't post the code here so added it to my main post

Comment: Can you please move `/System/Library/Java/Extensions/MRJToolkit.jar` file out of `Extensions` directory. Once you do it, try to start VisualVM with above command and post the output.

Comment: Am unable to move this. it's probably readonly

Comment: Tomas Hurka I checked the logs. it looks like the jar sunrsasign.jar is missing from the location. Rest of the jars are there. And also the directories User Directory          = /Users/kingshuk/Library/Application Support/VisualVM/8u131
  Cache Directory         = /Users/kingshuk/Library/Caches/VisualVM/8u131 were missing. I manually created them. Still doesn't work

Comment: The issue was fixed after reinstalling the mac OS. During the upgrade from Sierra to High Sierra, I think something got messed up, not sure what exactly though, but the re-installation cleaned things up and now it works. Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: The problem is back again, unfortunately. It was working fine last night though

Comment: I downgraded MacOS from Sierra to High Sierra and now it works fine. High Sierra is a mess so far